# How to use rlwrap in Gauche running on emacs in MinGW?

Tags: emacs, scheme

I am new to Scheme, and using `gosh` running on emacs buffer, in MinGW on Windows. It seems that people use `readline` or `rlwrap` to use history and more, but I still cannot figure out to accomplish the setting. Though it may be easy to run one on Linux using virtual machine, I would stick to Windows for now. Any idea or alternative suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `Emacs` buffer is not a real terminal, and `rlwrap` [will not run in it](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/1). However, this is no tragedy: almost all of `rlwrap`s goodness [can be had directly from `Emacs`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ComintMode) (you could use one of the existing `scheme` modes, or even [Emacs-gosh-mode](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-gosh-mode))

If you insist, Emacs [can provide a terminal emulator](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html) for you (`M-x term`) in which `rlwrap` will feel right at home.